# Como extrair uma palavra entre , e =?

Tags: c, array

Supondo que eu tenha uma palavra:

`char[1000]={"ALGUMA COISA,ALGO=TESTE,FIM"};`

A palavra antes do = e o próprio = são opcionais na frase;

Como eu faço para armazenar em uma variável a palavra ALGO da frase?

O código abaixo é o que eu tentei, porém, não está funcionando:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

 int main(){
char linha[1000]={"ALGUMA COISA,ALGO=TESTE,FIM"};`
char personagem[1000];
int ww=0;
int w1=0;
 int je=0;
                while(linha[w1]!='\0')
                {
                    if(linha[w1]=='=')
                    {
                        for(ww=w1;ww>0;ww--)
                        {
                            personagem[je]=linha[ww];
                            je++;
                        }
                    }
                    w1++;
                }
                personagem[je]='\0';
}
```

Supondo que o w1 é a posição encontrada "=";

Comment: https://code-reference.com/c/string.h/strtok

Comment: @MagicHat esse é um protótipo funcional, mas na teoria eu abri a frase tudo manualmente com laços de repetição... A unica palavra que não estou conseguindo é essa... Você saberia como fazer por laço de repetição? Strtok e strtok não iria dar certo nesse caso eu acredito.

Comment: O que é um MVP?

Comment: @MagicHat relacionado a empreendedorismo: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Produto_viável_mínimo (Minimum Viable Product) ou pode estar falando do Microsoft Most Valuable Professional https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Most_Valuable_Professional, se for o caso do ultimo (não sei o porque a pergunta surgiu, talvez devido a algum comentário anterior apagado) não é algo que você vai conquistar estudando e afins, é um título para os ativos em comunidades, uma especie de reconhecimento para que colabora muito mesmo com bom conhecimento em comunidades abertas sobre tecnologias microsoft.

Comment: Ele me disse que era um exemplo mínimo verificável o "p" não lembro, tipo mvp aqui do so meesmo heheh